# gdb eval "%s" replacement error

Tags: gdb

sorry about the title I tried hard to come up with something which would "describe" the issue. Sorry as well if the question has already been asked but I was not able to find something related.

So I was trying to use gdb convenience variable of type string with the *eval* function.

First, since I just started using gdb, I wanted to make sure I understand what's happening so I tried the following

```
(gdb) eval "!echo 5"
5
(gdb) eval "!echo 5+8"
5+8
(gdb) eval "!echo %d", 5
5
(gdb) eval "!echo %d", 5+8
13
(gdb) set $anumber = 12
(gdb) eval "!echo %d", $anumber
12
```

so far so good.
Then I tried this though and I cannot figure out why it's yelling at me for the last line.

```
(gdb) eval "!echo hello"
hello
(gdb) eval "!echo \"hello\""
hello
(gdb) eval "!echo 'hello'"
hello
(gdb) set $hellostr = "hello"
(gdb) eval "!echo %s", $hellostr
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

Is there something I am missing?

If that might help, calling *show version* produce

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just [a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13098) in gdb.  Currently gdb always tries to allocate the string in the inferior.  However, this is not always truly necessary.